# Heine Borel Theorem holds in this metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space such that every open ball in $X$ is relatively compact; that is, its closure is compact. Supposedly the Heine Borel Theorem holds in such a metric space. How can I go about showing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, one can prove that a set is closed and bounded if it is compact (this is not very difficult, but if you want to I can provide a brief proof). Now, if $A$ is bounded then it is contained in some closed ball and if $A$ is closed then it is compact.

Comment: and a closed set contained in a compact set is clearly compact (you can use the definition of compactness in terms of sequences to prove this easily)

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Or that in any Hausdorff space (metrizable or not), compact sets are closed, and closed subsets of compact sets are compact